# iMac theme for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, themes, login-screen

How to change the Ubuntu 16.04 login to an iMac theme?

Comment: Maybe this link could help you: http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html (Although, I think that the answer you received already covers it.)

Comment: @OwenHines Yes,

Answer (score 2):

This is the MacBuntu Theme:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7
```

Then, install Unity Tweak Tool from Ubuntu Software Center.
Select the Mac Icons and Theme.

To get a launcher similar to Launchpad Launcher:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install slingscold
```

Install the Plank dock:

```
sudo apt-get install plank
```

And install themes for it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-plank-theme-lts-v7
```

Use Ctrl+Right Click to access the menu and change the theme.

Install Mac Splash screen for Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-bscreen-lts-v7
```

Install Mac LightDM theme (**install at your own risk, buggy with some graphics cards and not very reliable- can brick your login**)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-lightdm-lts-v7
```

To revert:

```
sudo apt-get remove macbuntu-os-lightdm-lts-v7
```

Comment: I'd recommend elaborating on the warning for the LightDM theme as to what it could affect. Other than that, great answer!

Comment: @PatrickNegus How fix bug  Install Mac LightDM, in login

Comment: @TobiMuhamad There's no fix, its just that the theme is pretty unstable.